# Android menu is not working, who know how can solve it?

Tags: android, menu

I carate a new app and I used onNavigationItemSelected funtion, but when I click the cart, order and log out, it's not working. I don't what's happening. Has someone colud help where is problem?

this is my home.java code

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference category;
    TextView txtFullName;
    RecyclerView recycler_menu;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Menu");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Init Firebase
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        category = database.getReference("Category");


        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        //.setAction("Action", null).show();

                Intent cartIntent = new Intent(Home.this, Cart.class);
                startActivity(cartIntent);

            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView =(NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //Set Name for user
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        txtFullName = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);
        txtFullName.setText(Common.currentUser.getName());

        //Load Menu
        recycler_menu = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
        recycler_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recycler_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        loadMenu();
    }

    private void loadMenu() {
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(Category.class,R.layout.menu_itme,MenuViewHolder.class,category) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MenuViewHolder menuViewHolder, Category category, int i) {
                menuViewHolder.txtMenuName.setText(category.getC_Name());
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(category.getImage()).into(menuViewHolder.imageView);

                final Category clickItem = category;
                menuViewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        //Toast.makeText(Home.this, "" + clickItem.getC_Name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Get CategoryID and send to new Activity
                        Intent foodList = new Intent(Home.this, FoodList.class);
                        //Because CategoryID is key, so we just get key of this item
                        foodList.putExtra("CategoryId", adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                        startActivity(foodList);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onBackPressed(){
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == R.id.nav_menuhome){
            Log.d("TAG", "Menu");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_cart){
            Log.d("TAG", "Cart");
            Intent cartIntent = new Intent(Home.this, Cart.class);
            startActivity(cartIntent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_orders){
            Log.d("TAG", "Order");
            Intent orderIntent = new Intent(Home.this, OrderStatus.class);
            startActivity(orderIntent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_log_out){
            Log.d("TAG", "Log out");
            Intent signIn = new Intent(Home.this, SignIn.class);
            signIn.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(signIn);
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }
}
```

this is my menu > activity_home_drawer.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_menuhome"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_restaurant_black_24dp"
            android:iconTint="@android:color/white"
            android:title="Menu" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_cart"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
            android:iconTint="@android:color/white"
            android:title="Cart" />
        <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_orders"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_access_time_black_24dp"
        android:iconTint="@android:color/white"
        android:title="Orders" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_log_out"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp"
            android:iconTint="@android:color/white"
            android:title="Sign Out" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

this is my activity_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/overlayBackground"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        android:background="@color/overlayBackground"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
        app:defaultNavHost="true" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Who knows how can solve it? I have used Log.d, but it does not get any data, so I don't know where has problem.

Comment: Have you attached debugger and tested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to this

`Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Category"); FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Category>  options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Category>().setQuery(query, Category.class).build();`

And `Picasso.with(getBaseContext())`
to  `Picasso.get()`

Answer (score 0):

Aaa this adapter.startListening(); above the following code

```
recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and change this

`adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(Category.class,R.layout.menu_itme,MenuViewHolder.class,category) {`